# Is this a bug in the Oracle ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net-managed

I'm curious if this is a bug in the Oracle ODP.NET provider.  I created a parameterized insert statement.  I named one of the parameters ':EMPNO' and when testing it gave it a value of '8000'.  In the database the EMPNO column was defined as varchar2(4 byte).  However, the insert gave an error message of

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "HR"."HR_DEPARTURE"."EMPNO" (actual: 6, maximum: 4)

Here is some code snipets:

```
"INSERT INTO HR.HR_DEPARTURE (EMPNO) ':EMPNO'"
```

I then add a parameter

```
new OracleParameter(":EMPNO", OracleDbType.Varchar2) {Value = empNo ?? Convert.DBNull}
```

Create a command and add the parameter (there were multiple parameters thus the array)

```
DbCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());
```

I did some research and considered things like encoding and the fact that Oracle defaults to bind by position (instead of BindByName).  However, none of these resolved the issue.  I then took a shot in the dark and changed the parameter name to ":EMPN" and got the following error message:

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "HR"."HR_DEPARTURE"."EMPNO" (actual: 5, maximum: 4)

This clued me in to change the parameter name to ":EMP" at which time the query worked.
I find it very odd that the provider is enforcing the database column size on the parameter name in c#.  The database size should be an enforcement of the value ('8000' which I kept the same in all tests).

Comment: In 40+ years of writing software I've discovered two actual verified bugs in vendor-supplied software. I've thought I've discovered tons of them. This has led me to an observation: any time I believe I've found a bug it's extremely likely that the "bug" is located in my code, and that checking my own code over with a very fine comb is probably more productive than blaming the vendor (whose testing criteria likely are better than mine). Just an observation...

Comment: Thanks for your observation Bob.  I also agree that it is more likely for a single developer to have a bug in their implementation than the vendor.  However I do not think asking "Is this a bug" is the same thing as "blaming the vendor".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; the problem is that your query makes no sense.

`':EMPNO'` is a string with the literal value `:EMPNO`, which is five characters long.

To reference a parameter, don't write a string literal.

Comment: Re-reading my question I see I created a cut and paste error in asking it.  This isn't the question I wanted to ask, but your response is of course correct to the question I did ask.